# "Off-topic for Sports, but you should try ..." where?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

One of our existing custom-written close reasons is the "general questions about physical activity", which states

> Questions on exercise and fitness unrelated to a specific, competitive sport are off-topic here, but can be asked on Physical Fitness Stack Exchange.

But a newer user recently asked a question that, while not on-topic here, would have been an inappropriate choice for migration to Physical Fitness too.

However, it's almost sure to be on-topic at The Great Outdoors, which covers recreational snowsports fairly well.

Can we change the custom close reason to reflect this dual potential and avoid a selection/exclusion of the other Stack Exchanges to which Sports is related?

Comment: I had created a custom close reason: "Questions on **outdoor** activities unrelated to a specific, competitive sport are off-topic here, but can be asked on [The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com)." This was never approved by another mod. I don't mind a separate or combined close reason to cover what you're asking...but I would need approval from another mod for such.

Comment: A combined close reason would be better, since the point is that we definitely know of a suitable Stack Exchange, and it may be either or both of [options: TGO, PF].

Comment: [Another one here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/how-do-i-get-over-caution-of-going-fast-with-minimal-access-to-slopes), attracted a new user first answer, which was of minimal acceptable quality and treated the whole thing as an opinion thread. Can we *very pretty please* make this change? Which other mods do I need to pester to get things done or conclusively declined?

Comment: @MichaelMyers would be the other mod. Get a hold of him on chat (or maybe he'll see this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point in the last two months (October-November 2017) this custom reason was added to the list of *off-topic > belongs elsewhere* close-vote choices.

See below for an example of the menu open and the reason selected. This happens to be the question with ID number 1, no close vote was actually made.

Thank you to the moderators for completing this request.

[image: an example of a question with the new close-vote reason available and selected]